# JavaScript find index of div

Tags: javascript, arrays

That's my first question here so please don't hate me :)
Tried to look for it but I wasn't able to find what I need.
How can I print index of div with class .circle that has been clicked?
[Here's my code](https://jsfiddle.net/ybbsmhqm/)

```
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

for(i=0; i<circle.length; i++){

 circle[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   this.classList.toggle("hide");
   console.log(circle.indexOf(this));
 })
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @KobyDouek: In the above, that would always log `circle.length`. (But it's fixable.)

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro: I know. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: index of div sound awkward. What is the actual requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use `let` in your `for` loop and just `console.log(i)`

```
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

for(let i=0; i<circle.length; i++){

 circle[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   this.classList.toggle("hide");
   console.log(i);
 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small change: Simply convert the NodeList into an Array ( Arrays have an indexOf function):

```
 var circle = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".circle"));
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/kemabeqato/edit?output)

Alternatively, you could simply take the index of the iteration:

```
 var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

for(let i=0; i<circle.length; i++){
 circle[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   this.classList.toggle("hide");
   console.log(i);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "index" you mean its index in the collection returned by that `querySelectorAll` call, you can use `querySelectorAll`'s `forEach` (which is relatively new, but polyfillable):

```
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
circle.forEach(function(circle, index) {
 circle.addEventListener("click", function(){
   this.classList.toggle("hide");
   console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you loop through your elements with the `i` as an iterator, just declare `i` as a different variable by using `let` in you `for` loop and then you can just use `console.log(i)` to show each circle's index:

```
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

for(let i=0; i<circle.length; i++){

    circle[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.classList.toggle("hide");
        console.log(i);
    })
}
```

Comment: And is there a method to change the class of every other elements (opposite to this)?

Comment: @JakubMatwiejew ALL elements? or all elements under another element?

Comment: all circles without the one that was clicked

Answer (score 0):

May be useful for someone, the same solution in ES5, using closures:

```
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

for(var i=0; i<circle.length; i++){
    (function(i) {
        circle[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            this.classList.toggle("hide");
            console.log(i);
        });
    })(i);
}
```